# Visual 2013 / CUDA: C2061 syntax error Identifier texture, surface

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cuda

I am trying to test some code that has recently passed into my responsibilities. While the CUDA projects passed onto me work, I can't seem to get a [new Project] inside the VS13 [Solution] to work.

I've created a CUDA 6.5 runtime project. I've also added the dependencies needed for my own code.
Upon compiling, I receive several [error C2061: Syntax error : Identifier 'surface'] or 'texture'.

I'm currently at a loss as to what I am missing. I would guess there is some dependency I need to add to the project, but it is hard to find any relevant resources online when looking for this error message. I've already added "compute_30,sm_30" in the correct place (i.e. the same place as in the projects that compile).

EDIT: Relevant is that the file throwing errors is #included in someClass.h which is included in the main function.

As is pointed out below, the problem is that CUDA-specific files are included in the visual compiler.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered in the current form, as it does not provide any relevant information about code or problems you encountered (apart of the fraction of a single error message). Improve your question by providing the relevant code and the exact output from the compiler (Output window).

Comment: This is because I thought it was a settings problem. As the first answer points out, it is not. Editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the cross-posting [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/978027/cuda-setup-and-installation/failed-project-settings-in-vs13-syntax-error-surface-and-texture/), the root cause of this problem is that the code that involves `surface` and `texture` keywords is in a .h file that is ultimately being included in a .cpp file

In a VS CUDA project, by default, .cpp files get compiled by cl.exe, the windows host code compiler.  .cu files get compiled by nvcc, the NVIDIA GPU compiler/driver.

cl.exe does not understand the `surface` or `texture` keywords, and so throws the mentioned syntax errors.

The only solution is to arrange your project such that those constructs only appear in, or get included in, files that will be process by nvcc, which is the compiler that understands `surface` and `texture` (and other CUDA) keywords.

For reference, there are various CUDA sample codes (such as [this one](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-texture-3d)) that use surface and texture constructs, and also have project code partitioned between .cpp and .cu files.  You can study these if you wish for examples of how such projects might be organized.

Comment: I run into the same problem but `texture` keyword is in a `cu` file. How can that happen? I am on Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10.